# How to write a python code to get all the data from a particular date?

Tags: python, json

I have json file which has a list of ids and date. How to write a python program to print all the ids for a particular month from the json file

Below is the sample json data

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "Fields": [
        {
          "Name": "version",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "Cycle 1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "subject",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "1008"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "project",
          "values": [
            {}
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "linkage",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "N"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "cycle-id",
          "values": []
        },
        {
          "Name": "creation-time",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "2016-07-12"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "id",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "1"
            }
          ]
        }]}]}
```

I have just tried to load the json file from below code.

```
import json

f = open('defects-export-0-100.json')

data = json.load(f)
print(data)

# month = str("MM")
month = '09'
defect_items = []
defectIDs = []

for item in data["entities"]:
    for container in item["Fields"]:
        if container["Name"] == "creation-time":
            if container["values"][0]["value"].split("-")[1] == month:
                defect_items.append(item)

for item in defect_items:
    for container in item["Fields"]:
        if container["Name"] == "id":
            defectIDs.append(container["values"][0]["value"])
```

My desired output: All the IDs from the one particular month of creation date.

Comment: `month = str("MM")` What is the point of this?  `"MM"` is already a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is how you're referencing keys in a dictionary. You can get the value at a particular key with:

```py
x = {"key": value}
x["key"]
# value
```

I've made some assumptions about your data set, but this code works with the sample you gave.

```py
import json

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

#month = str("MM")
month = "07"
defect_items = []
defectIDs = []

# Loop through each entity
for item in data["entities"]:
    # Loop through each field
    for container in item["Fields"]:
        # Find the field with the name "creation-item"
        if container["Name"] == "creation-time":
            # Check if the value matches with the desired date
            # Assuming there can only be one value
            if container["values"][0]["value"].split("-")[1] == month:
                defect_items.append(item)

# Loop through the defective items
for item in defect_items:
    # Loop through the fields
    for container in item["Fields"]:
        # Find the field with the name "id"
        if container["Name"] == "id":
            # Grab the value
            # Assuming there can only be one value
            defectIDs.append(container["values"][0]["value"])
```

Comment: I want to get the ids from the month of September i.e., from 2016-09-01 to 2016-09-30. According to the data structure, there are 5 ids between this date.

Comment: You could change the `month` variable to be `"09"`. There are a number of ways you could get what you want, but you'll need to be creative on how you implement your ultimate solution.

Comment: I have updated my question with the above code. I have used the month = "09" but its not giving me the ids and still printing me all the data from the json file.

Comment: The code will grab the `id` of any item in `entities` with the matching month. The ids are stored in the `defectIDs` list. Print that if you want to see what the code grabbed. You might be looking at the results of `print(data)` which will just print everything.

Answer (score -1):

Once the data is loaded, you can interact with it as you would any Python object. Get all the items with:

```py
items = data['entities']
```

For the code below to work, create a variable `month` and set it to a string with the format `MM` (where `M` is a digit of the month: e.g. `month='01'` for January) so it exactly matches the correct month format of the data.

Then, run the following loop to collect the IDs:

```py
ids = []
for item in items.keys():

    id = None
    time = False

    for container in items[item].keys():
        if items[item][container]['Name'] == 'creation-time':
            if items[item][container]['values']['value'].split('-')[1] == month:
                time = True
        if items[item][container]['Name'] == 'id':
            id = items[item][container]['values']['value']

    if time and id: ids.append(id)
```

Comment: Have you tried your own code?

Comment: @q9i I have updated the above code, but the code is getting an error : 'dict' object has no attribute 'entities'

Comment: The new code should be working now. Also, try setting `month` to a two-digit code like '01' instead of 'MM' directly, which is just the format.

Comment: Its giving an attribute error. 'for item in items.keys():'
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'